# Java - Slick2D: How to retrieve last key pressed?

Tags: java, input, game-engine, lwjgl, slick2d

After a lot of searching, I haven't found a easy solution to solve this.

I am incorporating a keybind settings section and I need to figure out when a user presses a key and which key is pressed.

I am using the Java Slick2D game engine.
Slick2D java docs: http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/

Example (Doesn't work):

```
private void setLastKey(GameContainer container){
    if(clickedRectangle != null){
        lastKeyPressed = container.getInput();
    }else{
        lastKeyPressed = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't I say "Thank you in advance?", sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: It's bloat. There was a discussion in the meta about this. Basically, Stack Overflow is for professional Q&A, and things like "plz halp" or "thanks" distract from the actual question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `keyPressed(int key, char c)` in `BasicGameState`

```
private void setKeyBind(){
    if(clickedRectangle == null){
        lastKeyChar = '\u0000';
        lastKeyCode = 0;
    }
    if(lastKeyChar != '\u0000'){
        clickedRectangle = null;
    }
}

public void keyPressed(int key, char c){  //Overrides BasicGameState
    if(clickedRectangle != null && lastKeyChar == '\u0000'){
            lastKeyChar = c;
            lastKeyCode = key;
            System.out.println("Key: "+c + " KeyCode: "+key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `update` method, a `GameContainer` object is passed. You can use method `container.getInput()` to get an `Input` object. You can use that.

```
public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, int delta) throws SlickException {
    if (container.getInput().isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_N))
        System.out.println("N key is pressed.");
}
```

Quoting a comment on this post:

> You can't ask for what key is pressed because multiple can be.

Comment: This specifies one key, I want to figure out which key is pressed.

Comment: @Markusmoo Slick uses LWJGL's input and that only has single checks and no events. You can't ask for what key is pressed because multiple can be.

Comment: As was mentioned, you can't, because multiple can be selected.

Comment: @LeeAllan So I must check all keys?  If so, I guess I have a lot of typing to do.

Comment: @Markusmoo What are you doing? There's probably a way around it, if you can be more specific about it I can help you more.

Comment: @AnubianNoob It's alright I found a solution, I will post a answer in a second after I make sure it is flawless.

Comment: Nevermind can't answer my own question for 8 hours, I'm a new user with less than 10 rep.

Comment: @Markusmoo Yeah sure, in 8 hours post an answer.